# Not created file, in ubuntu server 12.04 Cron Job

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

someone help me please:

I have made a cron job in ubuntu server 12.04, the frist job recolete data from web, and set in data base, it's working well, but in secon job the python scrpit in reading database and should make a file from database data , but it not working.

```
 rub@myserver:/etc$ crontab -e
```

i've edit this:

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/rub/app/writeindb.py
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/rub/app/writedatafromdb.py
```

the last part of my code in python  writedatafromdb.py

```
 cursor.close() #close curso in data base
 conn.close() #close connecion in data base
json.dump(geojson, open('datafromdb.json', 'w'))
```

Comment: does it work from terminal? without cron? also, how can you tell it does not work? you may be missing what the current directory is, try to give the 'datafromdb.json' with full path

Comment: As a side note, you should always `close` files you `open` (or, better, use a `with` statement), _especially_ files you open in write mode. Python does not guarantee that the object will ever get destroyed. And if it doesn't, there's no guarantee that `close` or `flush` will ever be called, which means that last buffer of data that you wrote may never end up on disk.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative path in your code, so the file `datafromdb.json` gets written to the current working directory. But a cronjob doesn't run your Python script in the same working directory as you would in the shell. See [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951) over on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange website.

Use an absolute filepath instead; one that start with a `/` and spells out the full path to the file.